# How can you put a matplotlib artist in the background to overlay a plot on top?

Tags: matplotlib

I know I'm missing something very basic about how matplotlib organizes figures and plots, but I've searched the documentation with no result. I have narrowed down my question to something simple that will hopefully help me understand matplotlib a little better.

Given the following piece of code:

```
x_coords = [1,2,3]
y_coords = [2,3,4]
labels = ['A','B','C']
plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, marker = 'o')
for l, x, y in zip(labels, x_coords, y_coords):
    plt.annotate(l, xy=(x,y), xytext=(-10,5), textcoords='offset points')

circle = plt.Circle((2,3), 1.5, color='w', ec='k')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.show()
```

The circle gets drawn on a layer between the markers and labels of the plotted points. How can I control which layers these elements are drawn on?

Here is the drawn image for a visual reference:

[image: simple plot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the `circle` in your code is not a [`Figure`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#module-matplotlib.figure), it is an [`Artist`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#artists), more specifically a `Patch`. In matplotlib, a `Figure` is a top-level `Artist` which contains other elements, so your title is a bit misleading.

Second, you can place the circle below the other artists by specifying its [`zorder`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) kwarg:

```
circle = plt.Circle((2,3), 1.5, color='w', ec='k', zorder=0)
```

The artist with the lowest `zorder` gets drawn on the bottom layer, and the one with the highest gets drawn on top.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, zorder was exactly what I was looking for. Also, thanks for pointing out that my title was misleading, I changed it to say artist.